# If I cast Gust of Wind and then move, what happens to the line of wind?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement

Recently I cast *Gust of Wind* to push back a group of chitine that suddenly jumped the party. It worked surprisingly well but just to be safe, I wanted to place my wizard behind a statue to stay out of their reach in any case, while the wind supported my allies.

The DM asked me how the position of the line works when I move away from the original casting position. I don't know, I said, so I quickly looked it up but it didn't get more clear. He ruled that the blast of wind continued blowing from where I originally cast it, regardless of my wizard's new position (which is how I intended it).

Now after the session, reading the spell description still doesn't clarify it to me. Is there something I'm missing here?

> A strong wind 60 feet long and 10 feet wide blasts from you in a direction you choose. Each creature that starts its turn in the line must pass a strength save or be pushed 15 feet away in the line's direction. [...]
>
> As a bonus action, you can change the line's direction.

What is supposed to happen to the *position* of the line when the caster moves while the spell is still active?

Comment: I edited out the link in your question because it points to a site that hosts non-SRD content. [*Gust of wind*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/gust-of-wind) is in the SRD, however - here's the official wording: "A line of strong wind 60 feet long and 10 feet wide blasts from you in a direction you choose for the spell's duration. Each creature that starts its turn in the line must succeed on a Strength saving throw or be pushed 15 feet away from you in a direction following the line."

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### The gust moves with the caster

First, the spell does not target a point in space, it has a range of *Self*.

Second:

> A strong wind 60 feet long and 10 feet wide blasts **from you** in a direction you choose.

Even if you move, it will keep doing that: blasting from you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that detail! It was the text under the Bonus Action that confused me though. But after double checking the wording on PHB p.248 I see it restates clearly and emphasizes your point: "(...) you can change the direction in which the line blasts *from you*." That last important detail got skipped in the description that I quoted from the Wikia.

Comment: @Vadruk yeah, the wikia is pretty rife with stuff like that, leaving out important words or phrases (presumably because the transcriptionist thought they weren't *really* necessary).

Comment: I avoid the Wikia sites like the plague. For any game, they are usually full of headcanon and people's home-brew versions of things. Fine if that's what you're looking for, but not really worth all the landmines of bad info.

Answer (score 7):

### The gust moves with the caster

> Range Self (60ft line)

This is why I think the spell moves with you, because it is actually cast ON you.

Comment: I brought up 2 points and this was the *first*, what you say is part of my reasoning. Maybe I shouldv'e expounded a bit on it.

Comment: @Szega FFS I can't read. I will update my answer to not refer to yours.